# SyntaxError - unterminated string meets end of file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

This code works with rails app in coffee script

```
$(".batch").empty().append("<%= escape_javascript('<option>App</option>').html_safe %>")
```

but when I run below code gives error

```
$(".batch").empty().append("<%= escape_javascript('<option value="<%= batch.id %>"><%= batch.rkbatchno.titleize %></option>').html_safe %>")
```

Error I get while running app

SyntaxError - unterminated string meets end of file

syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting ')'

in file

update_batches.js.coffee:6:in `'

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape double quotes inside append function and use string interpolation inside ERB:

```
$(".batch").empty().append("<%= escape_javascript('<option value=\"#{batch.id}\">#{batch.rkbatchno.titleize}</option>').html_safe %>")
```

Comment: Code run without error but I don't get the value of {batch.id} and {batch.rkbatchno.titleize} rails code don't execute I think. Rails code work only when <%=  variable %> syntax is used

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to embed the html so you can try like this instead :

```
<% @batches.each do |client| %>
  $(".batch").append("<option value='<%= j batch.id %>'><%= j batch.rkbatchno.titleize %></option>")
<% end %>
```

**Edit**: I change my answer according to your comments. You don't need another partial if you just want to iterate through `@batches` to populate your options select (from what I understood of your issue)

Comment: How did you define `batch` ? Maybe you may use `@batch` from your controller

Comment: $(".batch").empty().append("<option value=' '><%= j @batches.rkbatchno.titleize %></option>")   using this gives error: NoMethodError - undefined method `rkbatchno' for #<Batch::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f74558f6788>:

Comment: @RajnishSingh i guess what you trying to achieve is append each `batch` in `@batches`  as a select option. If so, just wrap your code inside an `each` loop

Comment: As I have answered with another way to resolve my error. I don't want to use render(:partial => @batches)  Instead I want my code in a single file

Comment: i really don't understand what you trying to achieve now. If you're facing a new issue maybe update your question for more clarity.

Comment: It gives repeated value for batch whenever ajax request is sent and also it display all the batch at once not specific that belongs to client